# OpenVPN TLS Shake Error on IP Change. Advise Please

Tags: openvpn, linux-networking

I'll try to be concise.

My Linux Debian VPS host changed IP addresses. This is how they did it. **Quote**, "we simply changed the IP for your VPS container. On reboot, the OS you have running in your container (Linux) sees the new IP and takes it as its own." **Unquote**

I thought there was nothing to worry about as all the other services moved easily, SSH and everything else works fine when I connect via both IP addresses (old IP and new IP).

However, openVPN is having the TLS shake error as follows:

TLS Error: TLS key negotiation failed to occur within 60 seconds (check your network connectivity).

I changed to the new IP address in my client config of course. I also tried re-issuing my self-signed CA and regular certificates on their new IP address but it didn't help. I totally flushed all my iptable rules / firewalls but it did not help either. I am completely lost.

What do I need to do to fix this error? I would be really grateful for any comments / advices / assistance. Much appreciated in advance!

Comment: my openvpn does not have any ips inside its certificate? are you sure you did it correctly?

Comment: Yes, I am sure. Because it is working on their old IP address. Certificates do not have any IP addresses, client configs do.

Comment: i could move my configuration around my servers and it always accepts me. either the ip has an issue or the server... but without the logs nothing will be done ;) but is this question business related?

Comment: Yes, that's correct, it should always accept it. No, it's not business related. My guess is that it's not openVPN, the issue is with their network. It's clearly seen from the Error. I am not sure though. The logs only have the error mentioned in my question.

Comment: and your configuration is a secret also? ;)

Answer (score 0):

It had nothing to do with openVPN. They confirmed there was a problem with their network. It is exactly as it says in my initial post. "check your network connectivity".